# Navigation to another screen with data fetched in FlatList

Tags: android, react-native, flatlist

I am trying to navigate to another screen with the value which I fetched in my FlatList.

Just for example :

```
renderItem={({item}) =>(
     <Text style={styles.FlatListItemStyle} 
        onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate('AnotherScreen', {item: item.Value1})}} > ID : {item.Value1}
    </Text>
})
```

here is navigation js.

```
<Stack.Screen
      name='OneScreen'
      component={OneScreen}
      options={({ route }) => ({
              title: route.params.item.Value1
            })}
/>
```

so I want to navigate to another screen which uses Value1 as an argument.

but I am getting undefined.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be item not item.value

```
<Stack.Screen
      name='OneScreen'
      component={OneScreen}
      options={({ route }) => ({
              title: route.params.item
            })}
      />
```

You are passing the prop {item:item.value1} so the prop is item thats why you are getting undefined

Comment: Can you show the data array structure? or console log value of item.Value1

Comment: I have solved it, thanks for your comment which made me to think in detail. i had to change code in Another screen code where i was accessing item.value1 and i had changed only item. and problem solved. Thanks a lot for giving me hint. problem was not in navigation stack. but your comment made me to think another thing and problem solved.